# Laravel 4 to 5 upgrade: Eloquent relationships not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm trying to upgrade my existing Laravel 4 project to version 5. 
Model relationships are not working fine. Every time I try to access a property from `property_price` table it returns null.

My models are located in `App/Models` directory.

**Property Model**

```
class Property extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    protected $table = 'properties';

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $softDelete = true; 

     public function propertyPrice()
     {
        return $this->hasOne('PropertyPrice','pid');
     }
}
```

**PropertyPrice Model**

```
class PropertyPrice extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    protected $table = 'property_pricing';

    public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Property');
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
$property = Property::find($id);
$price = $property->property_price->per_night_price; // null
```

The code is working fine in Laravel 4.

Comment: Are you models namespaced at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify namespace in relation methods.

If you're using **php5.5+** then use `::class` constant, otherwise string literal:

```
// App\Models\PropertyClass
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
    // return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Property');
}

// App\Models\Property model
public function propertyPrice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PropertyPrice::class,'pid');
    // return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PropertyPrice','pid');
}
```

Of course you need to namespace the models accordingly:

```
// PSR-4 autoloading
app/Models/Property.php -> namespace App\Models; class Property
```